# Facebook Insights Object not returning lifetime period data

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to read lifetime value for the metric `domain_feed_clicks`. I am able to get day base data by default but it's not returning lifetime data, even though the API supports this. You can confirm this on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#domain_content

I am using Facebook's C# SDK. I am also having some problems retrieving Insights data using FQL so I switched to retrieve it in this way but it is also not working. Can anyone throw some light on what I am doing wrong?

URL : https://graph.facebook.com/{domain_id}/insights/domain_feed_clicks?access_token={access_token}

Comment: This question is old, but I ran into this issue and have not been able to find a solution!

Comment: Do you have a sample API call showing how you're trying to retrieve the lifetime metric? maybe the docs are incorrect or the API isn't working correctly